# Apply function over rows of data.table keeping the first two columns and results as a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

*Apologies for another 'apply to rows of data.table' question however I have not found a solution in any of the other answers.*

I have a data.table with >2 million rows and >5000 columns. I would like to keep the first two columns and collapse the remaining columns by some summaries.

Example: Translate this ...

```
 keep1 keep2         c        d
1:     a     A 568.62060 599.4427
2:     b     B 815.63027 728.9226
```

To this ...

```
   keep1 keep2     mean   median 
1:     a     A 584.0316 584.0316   
2:     b     B 772.2765 772.2765
```

Currently my solution keeps all rows and is not as fast as I had hoped.

```
library(data.table)
x = data.table(keep1=letters[1:5], keep2=LETTERS[1:5], c=runif(5, 1, 1000), d=runif(5, 1, 1000))

stats = function(x) list(mean(x), median(x))

x[,c("mean", "median") := get_stats(unlist(.SD)), 
    by = seq_len(nrow(x)), .SDcols = 3:ncol(x)]
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to prevent outputting all columns and instead only output column1, column2 and the summaries I have made, as in the example?
2. Is there a quicker way to do this?

**EDIT:**

To give some context to speed problem here is the speed in a million row ~50 column table compared to base R. It is almost 3 times slower. I assume this is because I am returning the whole table back instead of the columns I want so I am hoping for a solution to this.

```
    library(data.table)

ids = function(n) sample(LETTERS, n, rep=T)
nums = function(n) runif(n, 1, 1000)
x = data.table(keep1=ids(1e6), keep2=ids(1e6), replicate(50, nums(1e6)))

stats = function(x) c(mean(x), median(x))

ss = Sys.time()
y = x[,c("mean", "median") := stats(unlist(.SD)), 
      by = seq_len(nrow(x)), .SDcols = 3:ncol(x)]
Sys.time() - ss # Time difference of 1.408833 mins


ss = Sys.time()
y = cbind(x[,1:2], t(apply(x[,3:ncol(x)], 1, function(x) c(mean(x), median(x)))))
Sys.time() - ss # Time difference of 40.196 secs
```

Comment: Can you clarify what's meant by "restrict output to the first two rows and the summaries"?  I interpret this to mean x[1:2,] and assume therefore not understanding the question

Comment: I have edited to clarify.

Comment: To speed things up, perhaps take a look at the multidplyr package to spread the aggregations across different processor cores?  It's hard to say parallelism will be faster than the data.table aggregation, perhaps it depends on your dataset structure.  There's an blog on the package here: https://blog.dominodatalab.com/multicore-data-science-r-python/

Comment: melt data and process by group instead of by every row. Some of data.table aggregate functions are already parallelized

Comment: @jangorecki could you explain how to do this so it returns the data.table in the same format?

Comment: melt and dcast, examples you have in manual